# how to make openni_camera package to output 320x240 rgb and depth images directly

Tags: openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
in [openni_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_camera), i got to know that it's ROS API has parameters like:

~image_mode (int, default: 2)

Image output mode for the color/grayscale image Possible values are: SXGA_15Hz (1): 1280x1024@15Hz, VGA_30Hz (2): 640x480@30Hz, VGA_25Hz (3): 640x480@25Hz, QVGA_25Hz (4): 320x240@25Hz, QVGA_30Hz (5): 320x240@30Hz, QVGA_60Hz (6): 320x240@60Hz, QQVGA_25Hz (7): 160x120@25Hz, QQVGA_30Hz (8): 160x120@30Hz, QQVGA_60Hz (9): 160x120@60Hz
~image_mode (int, default: 2)

~depth_mode (int, default: 2)

depth output mode Possible values are: SXGA_15Hz (1): 1280x1024@15Hz, VGA_30Hz (2): 640x480@30Hz, VGA_25Hz (3): 640x480@25Hz, QVGA_25Hz (4): 320x240@25Hz, QVGA_30Hz (5): 320x240@30Hz, QVGA_60Hz (6): 320x240@60Hz, QQVGA_25Hz (7): 160x120@25Hz, QQVGA_30Hz (8): 160x120@30Hz, QQVGA_60Hz (9): 160x120@60Hz

Now I want the kinect to output 320x240 rgb and depth images directly, i tried to set this para in launch file but failed ,
How to set this parameters?

Thank you vary much~~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217252/how-to-make-openni_camera-package-to-output-320x240-rgb-and-depth-images-directly/) by [lligen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19238/lligen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are [dynparam](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure), not rosparam, so in launch file try something like

```
<node pkg="dynamic_reconfigure" type="dynparam" name="reconfig" output="screen" args="set /camera/driver depth_mode 11" />
```

for depth_mode, check the dynamic_reconfigure for more, e.g. list of available resolutions.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lligen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19238/lligen/) on 2015-09-09**:
thanks for your help~